# Gradle does not generate an output APK

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to generate an APK for my android project on the command line.
I am running

```
./gradlew clean assembleProductionDebug
```

The output I get is:

```
:app:processProductionDebugManifest
:app:processProductionDebugResources
:app:generateProductionDebugSources
:app:compileProductionDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:preDexProductionDebug
:app:dexProductionDebug
:app:processProductionDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageProductionDebug
:app:zipalignProductionDebug
:app:assembleProductionDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2 mins 29.574 secs
```

However, my build/outputs folder is empty. The same happens when I run 
./gradlew assemble

The only relevant thing I could search for is potentially https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.language.assembler.tasks.Assemble.html but how do I specify the objectFileDir in the build.gradle?

Note: running

```
./gradlew clean installProductionDebug
```

does successfully install the APK on my device.

Relevant build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'git-dependencies'
apply plugin: 'testfairy'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.androidas"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
             storeFile file("as.keystore")
             storePassword "***"
             keyAlias "as"
             keyPassword "***"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }


    productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId "com.antsquare.test"
            versionCode 1
        }

        staging {
            applicationId "com.antsquare.test.staging"
            versionCode 1
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    testfairyConfig {
        apiKey '***'
        video "wifi"
        notify true
        testersGroups "ME"
        autoUpdate true
        videoQuality "low"
        videoRate "0.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you try to find for this file? This file is not visible in Android Studio

Comment: It is {project}/app{or folder of your module}/build/outputs/apk/*.apk

Comment: By file do you mean the APK? I am looking for it in /<app>/build/outputs/apk/

Comment: yes there should be there if not clean your project and run `./gradlew build`

Comment: In <app>/build/  I do not have an outputs folder, only an intermediates folder. I manually created outputs/apk/ but it is still not put there

Comment: Use some file explorer not android studio

Comment: Yes, I am using ls -A build/outputs/apk . it is empty

Comment: Did you call  `./gradlew build` ? And did you see message that `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Comment: My mistake `./gradlew task build`

Comment: First clean your project by `./gradlew task clean` and after that call `./gradlew task  build --debug | grep .apk` from console you will see apk place

Comment: ./gradlew task build gives me a lint error:   android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add

```
android { 

     compileSdkVersion 21
     buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

     ...

     lintOptions { 
         abortOnError false 
     } 
}
```

in your build.gradle in `app` module.

After that clean your project by `./gradlew task clean` and after that call `./gradlew task build --debug | grep .apk` from console you will see apk place

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the build error, but the apks are still not made. In the output I see the following lines:12:14:13.906 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Packaging app-staging-release-unaligned.apk
  Output file /Users/jimwang/dev/test/AndroidAS/app/build/outputs/apk/app-staging-release.apk has changed.
  Output file /Users/jimwang/dev/test/AndroidAS/app/build/outputs/apk/app-staging-release.apk has been removed.

Comment: try `cd /Users/jimwang/dev/test/AndroidAS/app/build/outputs/apk`

Comment: and `ls -a` after that

Comment: in console in your android studio

Comment: there have to be these files

Comment: yes ur right, i was actually looking in the wrong folder that time. thanks !

Comment: I am glad that I could help you Good luck

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio,

If the build is successful but not generating

> .apk

file and not launching emulator.

**Solution**: Make sure the drop-down below **build** in **menu** or drop-down to left side of the **run** is selected to '**app**' then when you **run** or **debug**,

> .apk

file will be generated and the emulator will launch.

Comment: "Make sure the drop-down below build in menu or drop-down to left side of the run is selected to 'app' then when you run or debug," I don't find anything that looks like this.